# Is it possible to bind() *this to class member function to make a callback to C API

Tags: c++, boost, std

Is there a way to use boost or std bind() so I could use a result as a callback in C API?
Here's sample code I use:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

typedef void (*CallbackType)();

void CStyleFunction(CallbackType functionPointer)
{
    functionPointer();
}

class Class_w_callback
{
public:
    Class_w_callback()
    {
        //This would not work
    CStyleFunction(boost::bind(&Class_w_callback::Callback, this));
    }
    void Callback(){std::cout<<"I got here!\n";};
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Normally in C callbacks you also get to pass a void* pointer that contains context information.

Comment: @LokiAstari Unfortunately some library authors didn't get the memo on this, the most notorious offender being `qsort` in the stdlib.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to do that. The problem is that a C function pointer is fundamentally nothing more than an instruction address: "go to this address, and execute the instructions you find". *Any* state you want to bring into the function has to either be global, or passed as parameters.

That is why most C callback APIs have a "context" parameter, typically a void pointer, that you can pass in, and just serves to allow you to pass in the data you need.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in portable C++. However, there are libraries out there that enable creation of C functions that resemble *closures*. These libraries include assembly code in their implementation and require manual porting to new platforms, but if they support architectures *you* care about, they work fine.

For example, using the [trampoline](http://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/trampoline.html) library by Bruno Haible, you would write the code like this:

```
extern "C" {
#include <trampoline.h>
}

#include <iostream>

typedef int (*callback_type)();

class CallbackDemo {
  static CallbackDemo* saved_this;
public:
  callback_type make_callback() {
    return reinterpret_cast<callback_type>(
      alloc_trampoline(invoke, &saved_this, this));
  }

  void free_callback(callback_type cb) {
    free_trampoline(reinterpret_cast<int (*)(...)>(cb));
  }

  void target(){
    std::cout << "I got here, " << this << '\n';
  };

  static int invoke(...) {
    CallbackDemo& me = *saved_this;
    me.target();
    return 0;
  }
};

CallbackDemo *CallbackDemo::saved_this;

int main() {
  CallbackDemo x1, x2;
  callback_type cb1 = x1.make_callback();
  callback_type cb2 = x2.make_callback();
  cb1();
  cb2();
}
```

Note that, despite the use of a static member, the trampolines created by `alloc_trampoline` are reentrant: when the returned callback is invoked, it first copies the pointer to the designated address, and then invokes the original function with original arguments. If the code must also be thread-safe, `saved_this` should be made thread-local.

Comment: That works with any C++ compiler that supports globals. See the `saved_this` is a just like any other global variable...

Comment: @AlexisWilke The point here is that you can have any number of C callbacks, each carrying a distinct `this`. The global variable is only used prior to the actual invocation (and should likely be thread-local, or removed altogether using an additional allocation).

Comment: I think that the question is more likely about having many C++ objects using the same callback and for the need to know which of those C++ objects triggered the callback...

Comment: @AlexisWilke They can do that, although it doesn't **look** like it at first glance. The trampoline function created with `alloc_trampoline` stores the `this` pointer and copies it to `saved_this` prior to calling `invoke()`. `saved_this` is only used temporarily inside `invoke()` to get to the relevant `this`. So although `saved_this` is global, you can have any number of trampolines within a single thread. I've now amended the answer to demonstrate this usage.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work.

The problem is that `bind` returns a functor, that is a C++ class with an `operator()` member function. This will not bind to a C function pointer. What you need is a static or non-member function that stores the `this` pointer in a global or static variable. Granted, finding the right `this` pointer for the current callback might be a non-trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

## Globals

As mentioned by the others, you need a global (a static member is a *global hidden as a variable member*) and of course if you need multiple objects to make use of different parameters in said callback, it won't work.

## Context Parameters in Callback

A C library may offer a `void *` or some similar *context*. In that case use that feature.

For example, the ffmpeg library supports a callback to read data which is defined like so:

```
int(*read_packet)(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size);
```

The `opaque` parameter can be set to `this`. Within your callback, just cast it back to your type (name of your class).

## Library Context Parameter in Calback

A C library may call your callback with its object (`struct` pointer). Say you have a library named `example` which offers a type named `example_t` and defines callbacks like this:

```
callback(example_t *e, int param);
```

Then you may be able to place your *context* (a.k.a. `this` pointer) in that `example_t` structure and retrieve it back out in your callback.

## Serial Calls

Assuming you have only one thread using that specific C library and that the callback can only be triggered when you call a function in the library (i.e. you do not get events triggered at some random point in time,) you could still use a global variable. What you have to do is save your current object in the global before each call. Something like this:

```
object_i_am_working_with = this;
make_a_call_to_that_library();
```

This way, inside the callback you can always access the `object_i_am_working_with` pointer. This does not work in a multithreaded application or when the library automatically generates events in the background (i.e. a key press, a packet from the network, a timer, etc.)

## One Thread Per Object (since C++11)

This is an interesting solution in a multi-threaded environment. When none of the previous solutions are available to you, you may be able to resolve the problem using threads.

In C++11, there is a new special **specifier** named [`thread_local`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local). In the old days, you had to handle that by hand which would be specific to each thread implementation... now you can just do this:

```
thread_local Class_w_callback * callback_context = nullptr;
```

Then when in your callback you can use the `callback_context` as the pointer back to your `Class_w_callback` class.

This, of course, means you need to create one thread per object you create. This may not be feasible in your environment. In my case, I have components which are all running their own loop and thus each have their own `thread_local` environment.

Note that if the library automatically generates events you probably can't do that either.

## Old Way with Threads (And C solution)

As I mentioned above, in the old days you would have to manage the local thread environment yourself. With `pthread` (Linux based), you have the *thread specific* data accessed through [`pthread_getspecific()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_getspecific):

```
void *pthread_getspecific(pthread_key_t key);
int pthread_setspecific(pthread_key_t key, const void *value);
```

This makes use of dynamically allocated memory. This is probably how the `thread_local` is implemented in g++ under Linux.

Under MS-Windows, you probably would use the [TlsAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fibersapi/nf-fibersapi-flsalloc) function.