# How to use a std::function as a C style callback

Tags: c++, c++11, callback

How can I use a `std::function` in a function which expects a C-style callback?

If this is not possible, what is the next best thing?

Example:

```
// --- some C code I can not change ---
typedef void(*fun)(int);
void register_callback(fun f) {
    f(42); // a test
}
// ------------------------------------

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void foo(const char* ptr, int v, float x) {
    std::cout << ptr << " " << v << " " << x << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::function<void(int)> myf = std::bind(&foo, "test", std::placeholders::_1, 3.f);
    register_callback(myf); // <-- How to do this?
}
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to bind() \*this to class member function to make a callback to C API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848983/is-it-possible-to-bind-this-to-class-member-function-to-make-a-callback-to-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Long answer: sort of. You can write a C function to pass to the API that calls your `std::function`:

```
// --- some C code I can not change ---
typedef void(*fun)(int);
void register_callback(fun f) {
    f(42); // a test
}
// ------------------------------------

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void foo(const char* ptr, int v, float x) {
    std::cout << ptr << " " << v << " " << x << std::endl;
}

namespace {
std::function<void(int)> callback;
extern "C" void wrapper(int i) {
    callback(i);
}
}

int main() {
    callback = std::bind(&foo, "test", std::placeholders::_1, 3.f);
    register_callback(wrapper); // <-- How to do this?
}
```

Comment: In this case, you could also save the other parameters (`"test"` and `3.f`) in globals instead of the callback itself. It does not really resolve anything if you need multiple callbacks with varying parameters, that is.

Answer (score 16):

In most cases you can't.

But when you store a C style callback in your `std::function`, you can use the [`target()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) member function.

Comment: Hey, nice - I didn't know about this.