# Convert std::function to a function pointer

Tags: c++11, std

I have a function from the C library that accepts a function pointer
`int c_func(void(*func)(void*), void* data);`
I want to write a wrapper for this function that takes a std::function instead of a function pointer
Something like:
`int cpp_func(std::function func) { return c_func(func, /*there's something here*/);  }`
After googling, I didn’t find anything on this topic (I found the opposite topics: a pointer to a function in std::function). How can I do it? And is this even possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290476/how-to-use-a-stdfunction-as-a-c-style-callback

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a std::function as a C style callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290476/how-to-use-a-stdfunction-as-a-c-style-callback)

Comment: `std::function` is a template. You can't have `std::function func`, you need to specify the template parameter for `std::function`. What parameter do you have in mind?