# Error while binding telnet_event_handler_t using std::bind

Tags: c++, telnet, stdbind

I am trying to design [telnet-client.c](https://github.com/seanmiddleditch/libtelnet/blob/develop/util/telnet-client.c) in CPP. While initializing the telnet client, an event handler having the structure `telnet_event_handler_t` must be passed as shown below [(see implementation here)](https://github.com/seanmiddleditch/libtelnet/blob/5f5ecee776b9bdaa4e981e5f807079a9c79d633e/util/telnet-client.c#L216):

```c
static void _event_handler(telnet_t *telnet, telnet_event_t *ev,
        void *user_data) {
    // process callback here
}

telnet = telnet_init(telopts, _event_handler, 0, &sock_fd);
```

In my CPP code, I am calling `telnet_init` inside a class constructor using `std::bind` as shown below:

```cpp
telnet = telnet_init(telnetOpts,
                     std::bind(&TelnetClient::telnetEvent, this, _1, _2, _3),
                     0, &sock_fd);
```

However, `std::bind` throws compilation errors shown below:

```
Scanning dependencies of target client
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/client.dir/src/simple_telnet_client.cpp.o
/home/ravi/simple_telnet_client/src/simple_telnet_client.cpp: In constructor ‘simple_telnet_client::TelnetClient::TelnetClient(const string&, const string&, int)’:
/home/ravi/simple_telnet_client/src/simple_telnet_client.cpp:32:33: error: cannot convert ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, void (simple_telnet_client::TelnetClient::*)(telnet_t*, telnet_event_t*, void*), simple_telnet_client::TelnetClient*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&, const std::_Placeholder<3>&>::type’ {aka ‘std::_Bind<void (simple_telnet_client::TelnetClient::*(simple_telnet_client::TelnetClient*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::_Placeholder<3>))(telnet_t*, telnet_event_t*, void*)>’} to ‘telnet_event_handler_t’ {aka ‘void (*)(telnet_t*, telnet_event_t*, void*)’}
   32 |                        std::bind(&TelnetClient::telnetEvent, this, _1, _2, _3),
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                 |
      |                                 std::_Bind_helper<false, void (simple_telnet_client::TelnetClient::*)(telnet_t*, telnet_event_t*, void*), simple_telnet_client::TelnetClient*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&, const std::_Placeholder<3>&>::type {aka std::_Bind<void (simple_telnet_client::TelnetClient::*(simple_telnet_client::TelnetClient*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::_Placeholder<3>))(telnet_t*, telnet_event_t*, void*)>}
In file included from /home/ravi/simple_telnet_client/include/simple_telnet_client/simple_telnet_client.hpp:10,
                 from /home/ravi/simple_telnet_client/src/simple_telnet_client.cpp:5:
/usr/include/libtelnet.h:376:26: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘telnet_t* telnet_init(const telnet_telopt_t*, telnet_event_handler_t, unsigned char, void*)’
  376 |   telnet_event_handler_t eh, unsigned char flags, void *user_data);
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/client.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/client.dir/src/simple_telnet_client.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/client.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I am using GCC/G++ 9.4.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

### Update

Defining `telnetEvent` as `friend` seems to be working. BUT when using the `friend`, the `send` function fails by saying "send() failed: Socket operation on non-socket".

The `telnetEvent` is defined as shown below:

```cpp
void telnetEvent(telnet_t *telnet, telnet_event_t *event, void *user_data) {
  TelnetClient *client = static_cast<TelnetClient *>(user_data);

  switch (event->type) {
    // data must be sent
    case TELNET_EV_SEND:
      client->send_all(event->data.buffer, event->data.size);
      break;
    // more cases here
  }
}
```

In header file:

```cpp
friend void telnetEvent(telnet_t *telnet, telnet_event_t *event, void *user_data);
```

In class constructor:

```cpp
sock_fd = get_socket();
telnet = telnet_init(telnetOpts, telnetEvent, 0, &sock_fd);
```

Implementation of `send_all`:

```cpp
int TelnetClient::send_all(const char *buffer, size_t size) {
  int ret_val = -1;  // default value

  // get the current address
  char *current = (char *)buffer;

  // send data
  while (size > 0) {
    ret_val = send(sock_fd, buffer, size, 0);
    if (ret_val == 0 || errno == EINTR) {
      // try again
      continue;
    } else if (ret_val == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "send() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // update pointer and size to see if we've got more to send
    buffer += ret_val;
    size -= ret_val;
  }
  return ret_val;
}
```

### Question

How to call `telnet_init` from a class?

Comment: And what is your question? No, this is not possible to do with std::bind. Do you understand what `user_data` is for?

Comment: @KamilCuk: I also tried making `socket_fd` as an input to `send_all`, and then used `client->send_all(client->sock_fd, ...` but the socket still complains "send() failed: Socket operation on non-socket". Any suggestions, please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000663/using-a-c-class-member-function-as-a-c-callback-function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290476/how-to-use-a-stdfunction-as-a-c-style-callback https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848983/is-it-possible-to-bind-this-to-class-member-function-to-make-a-callback-to-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530465/working-with-stdfunction-on-c-libraries `static_cast<TelnetClient *>(user_data);` Soooo you passed `&sock_fd` and you are casting it to `TelnetClient` - that's invalid, assuming `sock_fd` is an `int`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: The `user_data` saved me. Now `telnetEvent` is declared as `friend`, and init is called as `telnet = telnet_init(telnetOpts, telnetEvent, 0, this);`. Works perfectly. Let me know, your thoughts, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a trampoline to jump:

```
class TelnetClient {
   static void trampoline(telnet_t *telnet, telnet_event_t *event, void *user_data) {
        TelnetClient *me = static_cast<TelnetClient *>(user_data);
        me->telnetEvent(telnet, event);
   }

    TelnetClient() {
       telnet_init(telnetOpts, &trampoline, 0, this);
    }

    void telnetEvent(telnet_t *telnet, telnet_event_t *event);
};
```

Comment: Wowww. Impressive. This is very clever. May I request you to provide an explanation about it?

Comment: Explanation about which part?

Comment: The `static trampoline` function, please.

Comment: The function has to be static so it is convertible to a regular function pointer -> doesn't depend on any hidden data like a class instance to execute and isn't a member function pointer -> doesn't need `this` pointer to call it. A trampoline is just that - it is called, and jumped to another function. `user_data` holds `this`, so we can convert `user_data` to a pointer to the class instance and call member function on it.